# How to make a loop if a condition is met

Tags: python, loops

I have been working on making a gambling game where you must guess a number to earn the amount of money that you bet however I want the game to continue forever as long as the "Player" still has money how would I do this?

Here is the code I have so far

```
import random

print("Welcome to gambling simulator the objective is to get as much money as possible without losing it all you start with 500 dollars, GOOD LUCK!")

rngone = int(input("Where do you want your range to be? >>> "))
tries = int(input("How many tries do you want >>> "))
money = 500
bet = int(input("How much do you want to bet >>>"))
winnings = bet*rngone/tries-bet
winnings = int(winnings)

if bet > money:
    print("You can't bet more money than you have")
    
        
for i in range(tries):
    answer = random.randint(1, rngone)
    guess = int(input("Guess! >>> "))
 
    if guess == answer:
        money = money + winnings
        print("CONGRADULATIONS! You won!", winnings ,"You now have", money,"dollars.")

    elif guess != answer:
        money = money - bet
        print("Not quite!", answer,"was the answer. You lost",bet, "you now have",money)
    if money == 0:
        exit()
            
    elif i == tries:
        print("You ran out of tries.")
        break
```

Comment: use loop `while True:`

Comment: or use loop `while money > 0:`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
import random

print("Welcome to gambling simulator the objective is to get as much money as possible without losing it all you start with 500 dollars, GOOD LUCK!")

rngone = int(input("Where do you want your range to be? >>> "))
tries = int(input("How many tries do you want >>> "))
money = 500
bet = int(input("How much do you want to bet >>>"))
winnings = bet * rngone / tries - bet
winnings = int(winnings)

if bet > money:
    print("You can't bet more money than you have")

while money > 0:
    if tries <= 0:
        query = input('You ran out of tries, do you want to continue? (Y/N) ')
        if query.upper() == 'N':
            print('Thanks for playing gambling simulator goodbye!')
            break
        tries = int(input('How many tries do you want? '))

    answer = random.randint(1, rngone)
    guess = int(input("Guess! >>> "))

    if guess == answer:
        money = money + winnings
        print("CONGRADULATIONS! You won!", winnings, "You now have", money, "dollars.")

    elif guess != answer:
        money = money - bet
        print("Not quite!", answer, "was the answer. You lost", bet, "you now have", money)

    tries -= 1
```

Answer (score -1):

create a function to check if the user still has money in the balance

if true then create a "for loop" it is a command in python I suggest you do research on this function so you can adapt into your code

Comment: how to `create "for loop"`?

Comment: in your answer it looks like you could runs some function which returns `for loop`. I would say `run` instead of `create` -  `if true then run a "for loop"`. And sending to Google is good as comment but not as answer. Maybe your answer is correct but it is NOT good as answer on Stackoverflow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).